# React Typography underline

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to make the Typography text underline like this

[image: Underline Text]

existing/ current code

```
        <Typography
          variant="p"
          sx={{ letterSpacing: '1.5px', marginLeft: '4px'  }}
        >
          Underline Text
        </Typography>
```

Comment: Apply `text-decoration: underline;` CSS rule to the style of that component.

Comment: how can i apply it using the Typography mui?

Comment: @kaito Try to add it like this `<Typography variant='p' sx={{ letterSpacing: '1.5px', marginLeft: '4px', textDecoration: 'underline' }}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `sx` prop then you can use it with `Box`. Refer official documentation [here](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/).

Here's the working example of the same at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-typography-with-underline-kmeks?file=/index.js)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

function App() {
  return (
    <Box
      component={Typography}
      variant="h3"
      sx={{ textDecoration: "underline" }}
    >
      hello
    </Box>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

Alternatively, you can also pass `typography` property in the `sx` itself for the [variant](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#typography).

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Typography
      variant="p"
      sx={{ letterSpacing: '1.5px', marginLeft: '4px',textDecoration:'underline'  }}
    >
      Underline Text
    </Typography>
```

This should work